# config.php and ingress in K8S

Tags: php, apache, kubernetes

I am new to Apache. Currently, I am working in K8S, and configure in ingress file which is included create tls certification. Can I add [www.myhostwebsite.com](http://www.myhostwebsite.com) in config.php as well? Thank you!